# Text with encrypted by CryptoJS AES method cannot be decrypted by C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I have a text that is encrypted with this method:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key);
```

First problem is that, Although not **key** variable has 32 characters (it's 36 characters) CryptoJS can use it as a key.

Other one is more important, I cannot decrypt this text with any library in C#. They are giving error or decrypt differently. How can i decrypt that in C#.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Check the documentation [*The Cipher Input*](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input): If the key material is passed as string, it is interpreted as passphrase and a key derivation function is applied.

Comment: Thanks for information. I read that document and understood the problem. But still don't have a solution for c# side. @Topaco

Comment: CryptoJS uses `EVP_BytesToKey()` for key derivation. Look for a corresponding C# implementation on the web.